# can't access hidden field value on code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
javascript:
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //draw a map centered at Empire State Building Newyork
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(28.536360, 77.398130);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        //directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("divDirections"));

        $("#btnGetDirections").click(function () {
            calcRoute($("#txt_schooladdress").val(), $("#txt_address").val());

            //alert("Hello Testing");
        });


    });
    function displayDirections(result) {
        var html = '<div style="margin:5px;padding:5px;background-color:#EBF2FC;border-left: 1px solid #EBEFF9;border-right: 1px solid #EBEFF9;text-align:right;">';
        html = html + '<span><strong>' + $.trim(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text.replace(/"/g, '')) + ', ' + $.trim(result.routes[0].legs[0].duration.text.replace(/"/g, '')) + '</strong></span></div>';
        document.getElementById('<%= distance.ClientID %>').value = $.trim(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text.replace(/"/g, ''));
        alert(document.getElementById("<%= distance.ClientID %>").value);
        alert(lblBrand.value);
        $("#divDirections").html(html);
</script>


 aspx code:

  <asp:HiddenField ID="distance" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>


 code behind:

  protected void btn_submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     string distancecla = Request.Form[distance.Value];
  }
```

i am setting value from java script to hidden field but unable to fetch value on click of the          button i can see alert of hidden field value but its not showing on code behind page ,on code behind page i am getting null value ....have tried many different process but still getting null value ...please help me out...will be really thankful to you...need a strict answer to it.

Comment: you sure you dont have anything in the code behind page load that is clearing the fields value..

Comment: yes, i am sure...made a check once again. its fine..

Answer (score 1):

It is server side control as it has **runat="server"** attribute:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="distance" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

You can simply access it with its id as it is server side control:

```
string distancecla = distance.value;
```

if you want to access from `Request` object then add **name** attribute for it:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="distance" name="distance" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

and in code behind:

```
string distancecla = Request.Form["distance"];
```

Comment: i have checked it as 
string distancecla = distance.value;
but still i am getting null value

Comment: are you sure it has some value in it?

Comment: yes, i have seen value through alert in javascript after click of button_submit ,its showing value but shown null on server side

Comment: i am unable to see submit button and on what event your js code is executed?

Comment: <asp:Button ID="btnGetDirections" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="190px" Height="30px"   ValidationGroup="application" CausesValidation="true"  OnClick="btn_submit_click"/>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Request.Form["distance"]`, then use standard HTML input tag and make sure you add `name` attribute to it:

```
<input type="hidden" id="distance" name="distance" value="initialValue" />
```

If you're using asp control then you can do

```
protected void btn_submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string distancecla = distance.Value;
}
```

Comment: i have checked it as string distancecla = distance.value; but still i am getting null value